# how to automate radio button in keyword framework?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, frameworks, apache-poi, keyword, browser-automation

i have group of radio buttons in my web application. i have tried almost every suggestion for its automation but it is not getting selected.i am using keyword framework in which data will be read through excel file.

here is my keyword code:

```
package testscript;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class Keywords {

    static FirefoxDriver driver;
    static Properties prop;
    static FileInputStream input;

    public void openbrowser() throws IOException  {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        prop = new Properties();
        input = new FileInputStream("F:\\DarwishKeywordFramework\\src\\objects\\objectrepository.properties");
        prop.load(input);
    }

    public void input(String testData, String objectName) {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty(objectName))).sendKeys(testData);

    }

    public void navigate(String testData) {
        driver.get(testData);

    }

    public void click(String objectName)  {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty(objectName))).click();

    }


    public String verifypagetitle(String expectedTestData) {
        String actualValue  = driver.getTitle();
        return actualValue;
    }

    public String verifyeditboxtext(String expectedTestData, String objectName) {
        String actualValue = driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty(objectName))).getAttribute("value");
        return actualValue;
    }

    public String verifypagetext(String expectedTestData, String objectName) {
        String actualValue = driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty(objectName))).getText();
        return actualValue;
    }

    public void selectlist(String testData, String objectName) {
        Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty(objectName))));
        select.selectByValue(testData);
    }
}
```

here is my code which reads data from excel:
package testscript;

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.AssertJUnit;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.rules.ErrorCollector;


public class ExecuteLeadTest {

    static Keywords keyword;

@Rule
public ErrorCollector errCol = new ErrorCollector();
    @Test
    public void runLeadTest() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        keyword = new Keywords();
        ArrayList data = new ArrayList();
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("F:\\DarwishKeywordFramework\\LeadSuite.xlsx");
        XSSFWorkbook workbook  = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("TestSteps");
        Iterator row = sheet.iterator();
        while (row.hasNext()) {

            Row rowIterator = (Row) row.next();
            Iterator cellItr = rowIterator.cellIterator();

            while (cellItr.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = (Cell) cellItr.next();
                switch (cell.getCellType()) {

                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    data.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                    data.add(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    data.add(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    break;

                }
            }

        }
        System.out.println(data);
        for (int i=3;i<data.size();i++){

            if (data.get(i).equals("openbrowser")) {
                System.out.println(data.get(i));
                keyword.openbrowser();
            }
            if (data.get(i).equals("navigate")) {
                String key = (String) data.get(i);
                String testData = (String) data.get(i+1);
                String objectName = (String) data.get(i+2);
                keyword.navigate(testData);
            }
            if (data.get(i).equals("input")) {
                String key = (String) data.get(i);
                String testData = (String) data.get(i+1);
                String objectName = (String) data.get(i+2);
                System.out.println(key);
                System.out.println(testData);
                System.out.println(objectName);
                keyword.input(testData,objectName);

            }
            if (data.get(i).equals("click")){
                String key = (String) data.get(i);
                String testData = (String) data.get(i+1);
                String objectName = (String) data.get(i+2);
                System.out.println(key);
                System.out.println(testData);
                System.out.println(objectName);
                keyword.click(objectName);

            }

            if (data.get(i).equals("selectlist")) {
                String key = (String) data.get(i);
                String testData = (String) data.get(i+1);
                String objectName = (String) data.get(i+2);
                System.out.println(key);
                System.out.println(testData);
                System.out.println(objectName);
                keyword.selectlist(testData,objectName);

            }
            if (data.get(i).equals("verifypagetext")) {
                String key = (String) data.get(i);
                String ExpectedTestData = (String) data.get(i+1);
                String objectName = (String) data.get(i+2);
                System.out.println(key);
                System.out.println(ExpectedTestData);
                System.out.println(objectName);
                String actualValue = keyword.verifypagetext(ExpectedTestData,objectName);
                try{
                    AssertJUnit.assertEquals(ExpectedTestData, actualValue);
                }catch(Throwable t){
    //              errCol.addError(t);
                }
            }
            if (data.get(i).equals("verifyeditboxtext")) {
                String key = (String) data.get(i);
                String ExpectedTestData = (String) data.get(i+1);
                String objectName = (String) data.get(i+2);
                System.out.println(key);
                System.out.println(ExpectedTestData);
                System.out.println(objectName);
                String actualValue = keyword.verifyeditboxtext(ExpectedTestData,objectName);
                try{
                AssertJUnit.assertEquals(ExpectedTestData, actualValue);
                }catch(Throwable t){
                errCol.addError(t);
                }
            }
            if (data.get(i).equals("verifypagetitle")) {
                String key = (String) data.get(i);
                String ExpectedTestData = (String) data.get(i+1);
                String objectName = (String) data.get(i+2);
                String actualValue = keyword.verifypagetitle(ExpectedTestData);
                try{
                AssertJUnit.assertEquals(ExpectedTestData, actualValue);
                }catch(Throwable t){
                errCol.addError(t);
                }


            }

        }


    }

}
```

here is html code for radio button

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-md-4" for="VoucherType">Voucher Type</label>
  <div class="col-md-6 selectType">
    <input id="VoucherType" type="radio" value="Corporate" name="VoucherType" />
    <label for="Corporate_Certificate">Corporate Certificate</label>
    <input id="VoucherType" type="radio" value="Card" name="VoucherType" />
    <label for="Gift_Card">Gift Card</label>
    <input id="VoucherType" type="radio" value="Adv" name="VoucherType" />
    <label for="Advanced_Payment">Advanced Payment</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please suggest me any method to select this radio button.. thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try `By click_radio = By.cssSelector("[name='VoucherType'][id='VoucherType'][type='radio']");
driver.findElement(click_radio).click();`?

Comment: Yeah, try out above suggestion. Also you have not mentioned where exactly is your issue? Are you getting any exception? _Failing to automate_  can have several causes.

Comment: Also I tried to run your code, it is opening a Firefox browser when it compares `if (data.get(i).equals("openbrowser"))`. That means at least it is reading Excel into `ArrayList` properly. Further, I do not know how is your properties file written, So not able to run further tests.

Comment: i m not getting any exception. i have used that method. but may b i m defining it in wrong class. can u plz exact suggest me where should i write down that code??? i have one class which reads excel file. and one class where all the operations are done.

Comment: #Login
username=//*[@id='UserName']
password=//*[@id='Password']
signIn=//*[@id='loginForm']/form/div[4]/div/input


#Leads
voucher=html/body/nav/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a
createvoucher=//*[@id='main']/a[1]
Corporate=//input[@value='Corporate']  these are my property file. i can go through create voucher. after that i cannot select voucher type.

Comment: I am guessing that the Java code runs on your server, so it has no relation to your question since the HTML runs on the client in a browser. The HTML (as far as I can tell) has no form action to post back to the sever when the radio button is clicked, or you just didn't give it to us.

Comment: it is solved thanks @fabersky.using css

Answer (score 0):

Use *JavaScript Executor* to select the radio buttons if tests are failing consistently.

Here is the code:

**WebElement elm = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.getElementById('idofRadioButton');");**

**elm.click();**